# How do I update Text with a Button in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Recently, I have been learning Java and now I have encountered JavaFX. My question is, how do I update/change `Text` by clicking on a `Button`?`

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Scene start;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        BorderPane startLayout = new BorderPane();
        Button testButton = new Button("+1");
        testButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
        });
        Text test = new Text("Counter: " + counter);
        test.setFont(Font.font("Consolas", 25));
        test.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
        startLayout.setTop(test);
        startLayout.setCenter(testButton);
        start = new Scene(startLayout, 1280, 720);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(start);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What happens here is that I get the `Text` in the top-left corner and the `Button` in the middle of the screen. The `Text` shows "Counter: 0". When I press the `Button` I want the text to show "Counter: 1" or "Counter: 2"... depending on how many times I press the `Button` but when I press it, nothing happens, the counter stays at 0 in the window. What am I doing wrong? or, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `test.setText("Counter" + counter);` in the event of the button?